# Mac Os Core Data App that shares database between two computers

Tags: database, macos, core-data, cloudkit, shared

I made a mac os app (with a large database implemented with Core Data). This app is private, I use this app only for my job (it is not sold on the mac app store). Now I would use this app from two different computers (two users) and it would be great to share the database between two users.
How can I make this?
I know about Cloudkit, but it is necessary to pay Apple development program to use it.
Is there any other solution, perhaps (free and) more easy of Cloukit?
thx

Comment: You can use sqlite or mysql for free with one machine acting as host. It's better to use a 3rd machine as the host.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is designed to work as the local data store of a single app. Apple’s CloudKit is the only way it really supports syncing. You could try putting the data store in a folder synced by Dropbox, iCloud Drive, etc, but it’s unlikely to work reliably. If getting syncing in your app isn’t worth $99 to you then you probably need to look at third party solutions like Firebase, but that probably means redesigning the app to not use Core Data.